# Not getting validation errors from the controller laravel react inertia

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8, inertiajs

Trying to get validation error in react component if a form is empty but nothing receiving validation errors

This is function calling on when form is submit

```
`const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('name', values.name)
formData.append('email', values.email)
formData.append('password', values.password)
formData.append('password_confirmation', values.password_conformation)
Inertia.post(base_url+'/users', formData)
}`
```

Getting errors in component

```
`const  Create = ({errors}) => {
       // component code
}`
```

In controller function

```
` public function store(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
'name' => 'required',
'email' => 'required',
'password' => 'required',
 ]);
 User::create($request->all());
 return redirect()->route('users.index');
}`
```

How I get validation errors from controller please help.

Trying to get validation error in react component if a form is empty but nothing receiving validation errors

Comment: show the component code

Comment: Thanks for your response 

Issue has been resolved after share inertia method add in AppServiceProvider File

Comment: @GhulamHaider Can you share the code you added to your AppServiceProvider.php file and where, please?

Comment: Add this function in AppServiceProvider.php boot function



Inertia::share([
            'errors' => function () {
                return Session::get('errors')
                    ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages()
                    : (object) [];
            },
            'base_url' => env('APP_URL')
        ]);

Answer (score 0):

Please, Use this code in your, AppServiceProvider.php (Inside the boot method)

```
Inertia::share([ 'errors' => function () { return Session::get('errors') ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages() : (object) []; }]);
```